# Data table error "maxn (N) is not exact multiple of this j column's length (J)"

Tags: r, data.table

I occasionally get this error when I'm using data table.  I had a hard time coming up with an example to replicate the error, so I apologize that this one is not very realistic.

(numbers vary for N and J)

The error seems to happen most often when I use the `unique` function in the j column.

```
DT = data.table(
    group1 = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), each = 3),
    group2 = rep(c('w', 'x', 'y', 'z'), times = 3),
    values = rep(1:6, times = 2))

## Works:
DT[i=TRUE, j=list(unique(group1), group1, .N), keyby=list(group2)]

## Error:
DT = rbind(DT, DT[1])
DT[i=TRUE, j=list(unique(group1), group1, .N), keyby=list(group2)]
```

Another similar example is as follows:

```
set.seed(3)
DT = data.table(
    group1 = sample(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), 1000, replace=TRUE),
    group2 = sample(c('w', 'x', 'y', 'z'), 1000, replace=TRUE),
    values = sample(1:20, replace = TRUE))
DT[, j=list(unique(group1), group1), keyby=list(group2)]
```

The first example gives numbers that seem to relate to the actual data, but the second example comes up with a strange number.

> ```
> Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , j = list(unique(group1), group1), keyby = list(group2)) : 
>   maxn (242) is not exact multiple of this j column's length (4)
> ```

Can someone tell me what causes this?

Comment: do `DT[i=TRUE, j=print(list(unique(group1), group1, .N)), keyby=list(group2)]` and look at the first 3 values.

Comment: The first three values are "a" "b" "c", I don't see your point.

Comment: I meant the 3 values as in `a,b,c`; `a,b,c,a` and `4`. Check my answer.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I actually printed the wrong example(s) at first.  I shouldn't have named everything DT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because by adding the new row, you're creating a list with `unique(group1)` which'll have, for `group2 = w`, the values `a,b,c` and `group1 = a,b,c,a` and `.N = 4`.

Now, when there's a mismatch in the number of elements, `data.table` tries to *recycle* the values. That is, since the 3rd value is 4, and the maximum elements for this group is 4, it'll try to recycle 4, 4 times. This is why you got N = 3, 3 times before binding the last row.

However, it'll not be able to recycle unless the elements to be recycled is a multiple of the length of larger object. That is, in case of `.N`, it's of length 1 and 1 multiplied by 4 gives the length of the larger value. However, 3 can not be multiplied by an integer to get to 4. So, it won't be possible to recycle the values...

As a test, do this:

```
DT = data.table(
group1 = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), each = 3),
group2 = rep(c('w', 'x', 'y', 'z'), times = 3),
values = rep(1:6, times = 2))

DT <- rbind(DT, DT[c(1,5,9)])
```

Here you've made sure that the `group1` size is 6 which you can get to from 3 (`unique(group1)`). So, this'll work just fine.

The take home message is that when there are uneven groups, the values will be recycled. And for recycling to be successful, the length of smaller objects should have an integer multiple of the larger object.

Hope this clarifies things.

---

**Edit:** For the second data, `242` is not a random number... If you do:

```
DT[, .N, by=group2]
  group2   N
1:      w 242
2:      x 249
3:      y 273
4:      z 236
```

corresponding to `group2=w` you've 242 elements. And `group1` has 4 unique elements. And 4 cannot be recycled completely to get to the length of 242 (4 doesn't divide 242 exactly).